# Using root class name in SASS for 3 nested blocks

Tags: css, sass, nested

I am trying to use `sass` nested feature to achieve the my output.

This is the `HTML` code:

```
<div class="title title--no-extra">
    <div class="title-element"></div>
</div>
```

I need to create the following `CSS` output using `sass` nested features:

```
.title.title--no-extra .title-element {
   // do something
}
```

This is my `sass` so far and the reason I use this because I don't want to repeat `.title`

```
.title {
  &--no-extra {
     @at-root #{&}-element {
        // do something
     }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this.

```
.title {
  $t: &;
  
  &.title--no-extra {
      #{$t}-element {
       color: red;
     }
  }
}
```

or this if you don't want to repeat .title anywhere.

```
.title {
  $t: &;
  
  &#{$t}--no-extra {
      #{$t}-element {
       color: red;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could assign the title class to a variable.
Like this:

```
.title {
  $t: &;
  
  &--no-extra {
     #{$t}-element {
       // do something
     }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I figured out two ways, to output it like u want (`.title--no-extra.title .title-element`)

```
.title {
  $t: &;
  
   &--no-extra {
     &#{$t} {
       #{$t}-element {
       color: red;
       }
     } 
   }

   @at-root &--no-extra#{&} {
    #{$t}-element {
        color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/f6d9cc4e6b2d6431b74bef6ba6feda6a

Comment: Variable is a great idea thanks but how to concatenate parent class with child class like this: .title.title--no-extra the output for your answer only displays .title--no-extra

Comment: for `.title--no-extra.title .title-element` u could do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mkewsybj/8/

Comment: Surly there must be a better answer don't you think?

Comment: Edit my code :) if you found out some more ways, let me know

Comment: you can do this

&.title--no-extra